# Numpy Zeros does not break zeros into array

Tags: python

edit, originally i thought this was a problem with passing the class, but then realized it was because when i do val = np.zeros((x,y)) i can not assign a value to val[i] , i found the reason is because although the documentation http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html  says >>>

```
np.zeros((2, 1))
```

returns

```
array([[ 0.],
       [ 0.]])
```

but when I do

```
ara = np.zeros((2,2))
print ara
```

i get

```
 [[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]]
```

which is missing the ',' and makes it impossible to index

I have some class with some initialized values

```
class myclass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stuffone = 0
        self.stufftwo = []
```

then i have some function

```
def myfunc(stuff):
    getstuff = myclass()
    getstuff.stuffone = stuff[0]
    getstuff.stufftwo = [stuff[1],stuff[0]]

    return getstuff

val = np.zeros((1,3))
val[0] = myfunc(stuff)
```

so I want to call myfunc, pass it some variables, then it should create a class instance and return it to me.  What I see so far is that inside of myfunc, i print getstuff and it gives

```
<__main__.myclass instance at 0x000000000486CC08>
```

so that makes sense to me, however, when i return getstuff, the value that is returned is just junk, I suppose

```
[  1.09268349e-317   1.09268349e-317   1.09268349e-317]
```

Comment: Are you sure, this is the actual code which is working?

Comment: yes sorry i was trying to make it simple and left that out.  the code now is the full class, and in mkpp I took out the long parts of matrix stuff, and that is the full end.  everything works in the mkpp function, and the print "MADE PP: " prints the instance, but once i pass it back its garbage

Comment: You were right in trying to make it simple (the full example is too complicated). The part where you went wrong is that you did not make the simplified example runnable and the larger example still has this same problem.

Comment: `when i return getstuff, the value that is returned is just junk` <-- please elaborate this, which is the actual problem.

Comment: actually as you see in the real code, it is spl[i], i tried it with just a variable and it is working.  There is something wrong with the numpy zeros

Comment: i was going to delete the post, but maybe someone can find this useful?

Comment: @user1938107 Please change `class myclass():` to `class myclass:`. When you define a class, you don't need `()`.

Comment: @BlackMamba you need `()` if your are defining parents of a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can´t use a numpy array to store instances off classes like this.
Look at the documentation!

```
=====
zeros
=====

Definition: zeros(shape, dtype=float, order='C')
Type: Function of numpy.core.multiarray module

[...]

Returns
-------
out : ndarray
    Array of zeros with the given shape, dtype, and order.
```

The array you create is of type `float` and not of type `object`.

Try:

```
val = numpy.zeros((1,3),numpy.dtype(object))
val[0] = myfunc(stuff)
print val[0,0]
```

---

**EDIT**

Pleae note!

This makes a difference:

```
>>> ara = np.zeros((2,2))
>>> ara
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])
>>> print ara
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with `np.zeros()`. You are missing the comma because you are using `print ara`, instead of just `ara` followed by enter. This makes Python print a "string" representation of the array, subtly different than the "repr" shown in the documentation. This display string has no effect on the behavior of the array.

Your code tries to put arbitrary "stuff" into a numpy array. Arrays don't work like that, they are typed and can only accept data of the proper type. `np.zeros((2, 2))` returns a two-dimensional array of `float64`, so you can only place floats in it.

Comment: thank you! Mailerdaimon answered just before you but thats was the problem